# How to extend a function by period and display it

Tags: plotting

I want to extend this function into a new function according to its period

```
Plot[-((E^x + E^(-x))/2), {x, -1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

and then draw this function as follows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a somewhat more general approach. It allows the basic period of the periodic extension to be any interval in its source function's domain.

```
Clear[f, xf]
f[x_] := -((E^x + E^(-x))/2)
f[x_, lo_, hi_] /; lo ≤ x < hi := f[x]
xf[x_, lo_, hi_] :=
  With[{span = hi - lo},
    Piecewise[{
      {f[x + span Quotient[hi - x, span], lo, hi], x < lo}, 
      {f[-x + span Quotient[x - lo, span], -hi, -lo], x > hi}},
      f[x, lo, hi]]]
```

The plot you request is then:

```
Plot[xf[x, -1, 1], {x, -5, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1.54}]
```

[image: plot_1]

But a plot making the period of `xf` the asymmetric interval `{-1, .5]` is just as easy.

```
Plot[xf[x, -1, .5], {x, -4, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1.54}]
```

[image: plot_2]

Answer (score 2):

One possible way

```
T = 2; (*period*)
f[x_] := -((E^x + E^(-x))/2);
fExtended[x_] := Piecewise[{{f[x], -T/2 < x < T/2}, 
                           {fExtended[x - T], x > T/2}, 
                           {fExtended[x + T], x < T/2}}];
Plot[fExtended[x], {x, -1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[fExtended[x], {x, -2 T, 2 T}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Let's replace x with  Mod[x, 2, -1]

```
Plot[-((E^Mod[x, 2, -1] + E^(-Mod[x, 2, -1]))/2), {x, 0, 10}]
```

We can get the result we want.

Answer (score 2):

This answer adds to Go with the wind's answer.

```
T = 4; (* period *)
x0 = -2; (* start of the function sampling*)

f[x_] := -((E^x + E^(-x))/2);
xExt[x_] := Mod[x - x0, T] + x0;
fExt = f@*xExt;

Plot[fExt[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image: repeating function]

*fExt* now repeats *f* in the interval $[x_0,x_0+T]$. The '@*' means [function composition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html). If you define `h=f@*g;` then `h[x]==f[g[x]]`.

Edit: made a function out of it for ease of use. This gives the same output as above.

```
MakePeriodic[f_, T_, x0_: 0] := Module[{xExt},
  xExt = Function[x, Mod[x - x0, T] + x0];
  f@*xExt
  ]

fExt = MakePeriodic[f,4,-2];
Plot[fExt[x], {x,-5, 5}]
```