# Finding the period of a function of an interpolating function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, periodic-function

I have two quantities of interest, `x` and `y` which are functions of $\theta$ and thus implicitly of time. They also depend on two parameters `a` and `b`. However, `y` is merely a dependent equation. They are defined and solved by

```
x[a_, b_] := a Cos[θ[t]]^2 + b Sin[θ[t]]^2 + θ'[t];
y[a_, b_] := 3 a^2 (Cos[2 θ[t]] + Sin[θ[t]]^2) - b Sin[θ[t]];
sol1 = First @ NDSolve[{x[1, 2] == 0, θ[0] == 0}, θ, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Clearly, `y` is a periodic function of time. However, if I try to find the period of this function using

```
FunctionPeriod[y[1, 2] /. sol1, t]
```

I get 0 every time. This seems to be a problem due to the nature of the solution as an interpolating function, but I was wondering if there is a good way to get the period.

Comment: An exact solution is `{\[Theta] -> 
  Function[{t}, -ArcTan[Sqrt[b] Cos[Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] t], Sqrt[a] Sin[Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] t]]]}` and then `FunctionPeriod` will work.

Comment: Another way to get the exact period: The time for θ to go from 0 to 2π is equal to `Integrate[1/(a Cos[\[Theta][t]]^2 + b Sin[\[Theta][t]]^2), {\[Theta][t], 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]`

Comment: An exact solution without the discontinuities of the ArcTan is `{\[Theta] -> 
  Function[{t}, -Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] t + 
    2 ArcTan[
      Cot[Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] t] (-1 + Sqrt[Sec[Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] t]^2])] - 
    ArcTan[(Sqrt[a] Tan[Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] t])/Sqrt[b]]]} ` .

Comment: Another way to find the period of the numerical solution is define `yy[t_] = y[1, 2] /. sol1[[1]] ` and minimize the quadratic difference `nmin = NMinimize[{(yy[3] - yy[3 + d])^2, 1 < d < 6}, d] ` to get `{4.84296*10^-14, {d -> 4.44288}} `  with 4.4428 as period. Choose suitable starting point from a plot of y[1,2].

Comment: So I realize that this equation has an exact solution - it was really chosen to illustrate a more general case where no exact solution exists, but that particular example would have been far too long to write out. Thank you for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

Plot the absolute value

```
absPlot = Plot[Abs@y[1, 2] /. sol1, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Extract points from the plot

```
points = absPlot // Cases[#, Line[x_] :> x, All] & // First;
```

Find peaks of the y values

```
yPeaks = FindPeaks[points[[All, 2]]];
```

Points corresponding to the peaks

```
peakPoints = points[[yPeaks[[All, 1]]]];
```

Plot to check

```
Plot[Abs@y[1, 2] /. sol1, {t, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[#] & /@ peakPoints}]
```

[image]

Depending on your definition of "period"

```
peakPoints // Select[Last@# > 2.5 &] // Part[#, All, 1] & // Differences
(* {1.56407, 2.87684, 1.56662, 2.87797} *)

peakPoints // Select[Last@# < 2.5 &] // Part[#, All, 1] & // Differences
(* {4.44382} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

re Let's look at expressions you working with in more detail than you provide.

```
x[a_, b_] := a Cos[θ[t]]^2 + b Sin[θ[t]]^2 + θ'[t]
y[a_, b_] := 3 a^2 (Cos[2 θ[t]] + Sin[θ[t]]^2) - b Sin[θ[t]]
```

I think it's easier to work with `θ` as pure function, so I use `NDSolveValue` to solve for it.

```
θ = NDSolveValue[{x[1, 2] == 0, θ[0] == 0}, θ, {t, 0, 3 π}]
```

Now we can plot `y[1, 2]` over the domain of `θ`:

```
Plot[y[1, 2], {t, 0, 3 π}]
```

[image: plot]

It does look periodic, doesn't it? But, of course, it's not. It's just a good polynomial approximation to a periodic function over a small closed interval of the reals. However, you can get a decent numerical approximation of the period of the function being approximated by computing the interval between the two negative minima shown int plot. Like so:

```
Subtract @@ Flatten[FindArgMin[y[1, 2], {t, #}] & /@ {8, 33/10}]
```

> ```
> 4.44288
> ```

Note: Should you want to create a real periodic function from `y[1, 2]`, you will find methods for doing that by following [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/213013/3066)