# V 13.2 gives TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"] on code which works before. Why?

Tags: recursion, version-13.2

**Update June 25, 2023**.  Problem still there in V 13.3. Added screen shot at end.

---

I was trying code which worked all the time:

[How to extend a function by period and display it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213013/how-to-extend-a-function-by-period-and-display-it)

I find that in V 13.2 it now gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why is that? has something changed in V 13.2 to explain this?

Below I will give the code in plain text, and then screen shot showing it works in V 13.1 but not in V 13.2. This is all done from clean kernel and on windows 10.

```
T = 2; (*period*)
f[x_] := -((E^x + E^(-x))/2);
fExtended[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{f[x], -T/2 < x < T/2}, {fExtended[x - T], 
     x > T/2}, {fExtended[x + T], x < T/2}}];
Plot[fExtended[x], {x, -2*T, 2*T}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image]

Comment: Plot tries first to simplify f symbolically. Because of `fExtended[x - T]` this creates a recursion. If you restrict f to numerical values you can prevent the recursion: `fExtended[x_?NumericQ] :=...` Why this worked in 13.1 I do not know.

Comment: @DanielHuber I noticed that too. But something is not right. It should actually work without this _?NumericQ. Also this function is used symbolically later on in the code so I do not want x to be numeric in the definition. But the whole point this code always worked with no error. So something basic has changed to cause this to now fail.

Comment: `TerminatedEvaluation` is new. Maybe in the old version the `Plot` has already generated recursion limit message but been suppressed.

Comment: I don't know why but using `$RecursionLimit = 1024*9` in a `Block` or `Plot[fExtended @@ {x}, ... ]` works in 13.2 :)

Comment: Probably a bug. Will investigate.

Comment: (1) Also there is a way to switch this off. It is SetSystemOptions[“EvaluateExceptions”->False]. Or something like that (I am unable to check right now).

Comment: (2) while ordinarily I do not like bug reports posted, this case is confusing to users above and beyond the usual bug. If others have encountered this type of result in unexpected situations, I for one have no objection to posting them here. I cannot speak for the moderators though.

Comment: `"EvaluateErrorExceptions"` is the actual option name.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: Thank you for reporting. I Just encountered a similar problem with DSolve. Reevaluated an old notebook that solves a bunch of differential equations (successfully with older versions) and had one of them fail with `TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]`. Setting `$RecursionLimit` to a value 10 times its default does make Mathematica solve the equation.

Comment: @Nasser is 13.3 out? Which product are you using Wolfram Desktop or Mathematica?

Comment: @user13892 V 13.3 is out on the cloud only now. That is where I am using is. If you have Wolfram account, you can do that also.

Comment: Seeing this in 13.3 when computing analytic sums and integrals that should be completely trivial and have been in the past. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @starfish Please provide examples of the ones still in 13.3. And Nasser (can't use @ twice but it's your thread) I apologize for this one remaining. If time permits, and nobody gets to it sooner, I'll try to deal with it for the next release.