# `TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit]` while computing the Fourier series of a signal

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to compute the Fourier series of the signal below (the vertical blue lines of its first period are strangely omitted by calling `Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 20}]`!).

```
f[t_] := Which[0 < t <= 1, 1, 1<t <= 2,-1,  2 < t <=4, 0, t > 4, f[t -4]]
```

[image]

So, I tried `FourierSeries[f[t], t, 3]`, but I get the error `TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be a bug in that code. One thing to try is recasting the function using Piecewise, as that might play nicer with FourierSeries.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278783/v-13-2-gives-terminatedevaluationrecursionlimit-on-code-which-works-before see above for similar message

Comment: If the last argument is replaced by Unevaluated[f[t - 4]] , then computation  finishes, though I am not sure about correctness,

Comment: (1) Use `Mod[t, 4]` instead of recursion. The system is not programmed to detect periodicity defined by recursion. It seems to try to resolve the recursion using a symbolic `t`, which is not possible. (2) The default period of `FourierSeries[]` is 2π, which is not the period of `f[t]`. (3) A surface-level analysis of `f[t]` by `Plot[]` reveals potential discontinuities at t = 0, 1, 2, 4, but `Plot` won't do an inductive analysis of `f[t-4]`. So `Plot` breaks the graph at these, and only these, values.